# RethinkDB: how many connections?

Tags: python, tornado, gevent, rethinkdb

I'm starting out with `rethinkdb` in `python`, and taking a look at the different approaches:

1. Blocking approach with threads
2. Non-blocking, callback-based approach with `Tornado`
3. Greenlet-based approach with `gevent`

In the first case, the natural thing to do is to give each thread a `connection` object. In the second and third cases, however, I don't quite get it.

With tornado and gevent, how and when should I create connections? How many should I have around?

Comment: One thing you have to consider with gevent is that is not working on python 3  and I doubt it will be ever ported. 
Of course there are some forks out there that may be work but I am not very hopeful for future support. 
May be this takes one parameter out of the equation and makes your decision a little simpler. :-)

Answer (score 6):

If you're using a non-blocking library, one connection should be sufficient in RethinkDB 2.0 (prior to 2.0 there was less per-connection parallelism).  Per-connection overhead is pretty low, though.  Some people open a connection per query and even that isn't too slow, so you should just do whatever's easiest.

EDIT: This advice is now outdated.  For newer versions of RethinkDB using one connection per query is strongly discouraged.  One connection per thread is still fine.